# wso2 mb 2.2.0 startup error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wso2-esb

i have installed wso2 mb 2.2.0 , when start up But the start-up procedure failed with the following error message.

os: windows 7 32b

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-17"
[2014-08-15 20:53:02,666] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager} -  Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1)
:9160
[2014-08-15 20:53:02,667]  INFO {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Host detected as down was added to retry queue: localh
ost(127.0.0.1):9160
[2014-08-15 20:53:03,331]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener} -  HTTPS port       : 9443
[2014-08-15 20:53:03,331]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener} -  HTTP port        : 9763
[2014-08-15 20:53:03,342] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Cannot start transports
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and was using Java 7. 
Switching to Java(jre/jdk) 8 solved the problem for me.